# Cosine Rules for triangle in java

Tags: java, math

i am working on a program in java that allows the user to calculate all angles and sides depending on the user choice. For the angle its working fine but to get the side its giving wrong answers.

This is codefor side A only :

```
public class CosCalc {
//to get length of side a given angle A and sides a and c
public static double getSideA(double A, double b, double c) {

    return (double) Math.sqrt((Math.pow(b, 2) + Math.pow(c, 2)) - 2 * b * c * Math.cos(A));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 double A,B,C,a,b,c;
       int option1, option2,option3; //option4, option5, option6;
            option1 = scan.nextInt();
       
                if (option1 == 1){
                    System.out.println("Please enter 1 to calculate a for side a\nOr enter 2  side b\nOr 3 for side c");
                        option2 = scan.nextInt();
                    if(option2 == 1){
System.out.println("Enter size of Angle A: ");
                    A = scan.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter length of side b:");
                    b = scan.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter length of side c:");
                    c = scan.nextDouble();
                      //CosCalc side = new CosCalc(); 
                        double result1 = getSideA(A,b,c);
                        System.out.println("Therefore the lenght of side a is: "+result1);
}
}
}
```

The expected out if for example the user enters:
48 for Angle A
17 for side b
and 20 for side c
result for side a should be 15.3 or something around there.

istead its giving me 29 which is wrong. need help

Comment: Sounds like you're using degrees for the angle -- Math.cos uses radians.

Comment: What comment above says. Also check that you don't accidentally convert `double` to `int` when you're multiplying by `2` in the `getSideA`.

Comment: what should i use then or how should i write it

Comment: [How to convert degrees to radians](https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-Degrees-to-Radians) - it's simple: multiply by `Math.PI / 180.0`.